# How do I convert a hex string to pcap-file using Python?

Tags: python, string, hex, converters, pcap

I have a Python-script, which converts files to the hex string. Now I need to convert these strings to the pcap-file. The hex string after converting from png-file is about 174 pages of Word file. The code, which I use to make a string:

```
 filename = 'test.png'
 with open(filename, 'rb') as f:
 img = f.read()
 print(binascii.hexlify(img))
```

So, is it even possible to do such converter?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? What is the problem you are solving here?

Comment: I'm trying to make a scanning program, which will check the png-files and reveal malicious code, if such code is inside.

Comment: So what does this have to do with pcap?

Comment: Cause I wanted to use Wireshark for analyzing the data.

Comment: Wireshark is to analyze network traffic; not programs. Unless your image has embedded network traffic **logs**, wireshark won't be of much help.

Comment: Thats the point - image has such logs.

Comment: If it has logs (like, say Apache logs); you can't reconstruct a pcap file from those. A pcap file captures _packet data_, and application logs don't contain that information. Have a look at the [pcap data file format](https://wiki.wireshark.org/Development/LibpcapFileFormat) and you can see if the data required is available embedded in your image.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the tool text2pcap tool ([wireshark tool](https://www.wireshark.org/docs/man-pages/text2pcap.html))

This is an example for a function that use this tool:

```
def string_to_pcap_file(packet_string, output_pcap_file):
    cmd = "echo 0000    " + packet_string + " >> tmp.txt"
    os.system(cmd)
    cmd = "text2pcap " + "tmp.txt " + output_pcap_file 
    os.system(cmd)
    os.system("rm tmp.txt")

mac_da = '00 11 22 33 44 55 '
mac_sa = '55 55 55 55 55 55 '
vlan = '81 00 11 22 '
ether_type = '08 00 '
data = '45 00 00 2a 04 d2 00 00 7f 06 36 fd 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 '
temp_str = mac_da + mac_sa + ether_type + data

string_to_pcap_file(temp_str, 'new_pcap_file.pcap')
```